# Use other class methods and fields inside another

Tags: java, oop, classloader

I have a conceptual question.( some questions ! )
Let explain it with a real project.
I have a `Login` `swing` form,it has the main method and application starts from here.

```
  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Login().setVisible(true);
        }
    }); // this method is inside main Method
```

The `Login` Form contains some `TextField`s and `Button`s,And also some `methods`.
( For example when I press the `Enter` Button some authenticatation and action perform )
After press Enter Button, if authenticate success it goes to another form named `MainTabbedForm`.
Now the question is about `Object Oriented Programming` and class loading.
I want to access the `Login` Form form the `MainTabbedForm`. For example I want to `dispose` the `Login` Form after authentications successfully, And wanna do it in the `MainTabbedForm` constructor. I write a method inside the `Login` class to connect the Login  to the MainTabbedForm. In this way :

```
public void disappearForm(MainTabbedForm form) {
this.form=form; // I already has defined a MainTabbedForm field in top of the Login class
this.dispose(); // Dispose the Login class
}
```

And use it in the constructor of the MainTabbedForm, Before using just declare a Login Form as a field in MainTabbedForm;

```
public MainTabbedForm(Login login) { 
   this.login=login;
   login.disappearForm(this)
}
```

But it gives me NullPointException because the Login has not initialize.
And if i make a new class of Login, of course it is a new class and will not DO the thing i want, because is a new instance and not the first created `Login` in main method.
Now I have a question, How can i connect these two class to each other?
Of course I can make a static method to do my job ! But i do not want to do that in this way.
I think because of this class loading and art of programming the frameworks and design patterns like `OSGi` and `MVC` and others has created, to mange loading and accessing services and objects and other things more dynamically, am i right?
Now the reply to these answers are really appreciate !

Comment: Why do you want to call `dispose()` from the `MainTabbedForm`?  How are you creating the `MainTabbedForm`?  Why does it also pass a reference to *itself* to the `disappearForm()` method?

Answer (score 0):

In `Login` you could do:

```
MainTabbedForm mtf = MainTabbedForm(); //create 
//set the required information using setters 
//for example set userName which is defined in Login to MainTabbedForm
mtf.setUserName(this.userName); 
//....
this.dispose(); //when no longer needed
```